# Problema al hacer push en GitHub con tokens

Tags: git, git-push

Estoy tratando de hacer `push` a un repositorio de GitHub, ya que no me deja renombrar archivos desde la web.

Primero agregué un token:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Luego hago lo siguiente:

`git remote add origin https://SHA256:xMeYS+hqKSuPIH2GaFMh0DbcnK+o5IRPINKpTQ3KBmY@github.com/arteze/varoish.git/`

Por último hago push:

```
git push --set-upstream origin main
```

Sale el siguiente error:

```
git: 'credential-osxkeychain'no es un comando de git. Mira 'git --help'.
remote: Support for password authentication was removed on August 13, 2021. Please use a personal access token instead.
remote: Please see https://github.blog/2020-12-15-token-authentication-requirements-for-git-operations/ for more information.
fatal: Autenticación falló para 'https://github.com/arteze/varoish.git/'
```

Estoy en Linux.

¿En qué me estoy equivocando?

Comment: Eso que muestras no es un *token*, es una llave SSH, creo que has mezclado los conceptos de autenticación de Github. El token sustituye al password en el sistema de autenticación basado en usuario / password. Para más información puedes leer la [documentación](https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/keeping-your-account-and-data-secure/creating-a-personal-access-token#using-a-token-on-the-command-line). Saludos

Comment: @MauricioContreras Estoy buscando una respuesta ya que tengo dificultades al usar GitHub desde la web, incluso yo no podía entrar al settings, pero ya descubrí cómo, aún sigo con problemas.

Comment: @MauricioContreras Ya lo solucioné, estoy agregando la respuesta.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La URL para generar los token:

- https://github.com/settings/tokens/

Un token se ve de la siguiente manera (en vez de asteriscos, son letras)

```
ghp_************************************
```

*Nota: Siempre comienza con `ghp_`, al parecer significa GitHub Personal.*

Una vez generado, hay que guardarlo, porque la página no lo volverá a mostrar nuevamente.

Una vez hecho eso, se puede usar los comandos de bash:

```
git remote remove origin
git remote add origin https://ghp_************************************@github.com/arteze/varoish.git/
git push --set-upstream origin main
```